# How to escape quotes while adding string as a header for csv in Python?

Tags: python, string, csv

I have a string from another variable **str1** and they already have values like 'a','b','c' (comma separated). 
So I want this string to be the header of a csv file that I am writing.
This works fine, when I use writer.writerow of csv reader 
but it puts a "" around the whole " 'a','b','c' ".

But, I want 'a' to be header for col1 and 'b' to be header for col2 and so on...

Pasting data:
printing only str1 prints :

```
'AV, AZ$$38060','BB, BZ$$31100','CO, CZ$$31120'.... till X.
```

But when I use it in writer.writerow,
It gives -

```
'YEAR'," 'AV, AZ$$38060','BB, BZ$$31100','CO, CZ$$31120' ", 'Index'.
```

How to make csv writer understand that I want the str1 without the enclosed double quotes in the end?

Code: (pretty basic so far)

```
with open('478558_output_new.csv') as sample,
open('478558_output_final.csv','w') as output:
 reader = csv.reader(sample)
 writer = csv.writer(output)
 # discard input header
 next(reader)
 # write new output header
 writer.writerow(['YEAR',str1,'Index'])
```

Comment: So, you have the name of every column in a string and you want to split the string and delete ' characters?

Comment: No I want to actually only remove the double quotes when using the writer.writerow.

Comment: Have you tried what I say in the asnwer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split a string into a list with the split('CHARACTER') method:

```
yourSring = " 'a','b','c' "
yourList = yourString.split(',')
```

In your code:

```
writer.writerow(['YEAR']+str1.split(',')+['Index'])
```

Comment: This is only printing the same string with a comma.

Comment: This is my output.. YEAR,"[""'AV"", "" AZ$$38060'"", ""'BB"", "" BZ$$31100'"" ].

Comment: Out put required is 'YEAR', 'AV, AZ$$38060','BB, BZ$$31100','CO, CZ$$31120' , 'Index' (only remove the double quotes enclosed in the end - these " "

Comment: I see the problem on my last answer, try now please